# Rails + Heroku : SMTP error for mailer (Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.1) , but only sometimes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app where when users register they get a confirmation email set to them.

here's the users controller create action:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      log_in(@user)
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: "Welcome to Pholder, #{@user.name}!" }
      format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

as you can see after @user.save there is a mailer. However, a person just told me he got an error ("we're sorry, something went wrong") on heroku after trying to register, so I tried it myself and also got an error

```
2012-11-16T17:21:28+00:00 app[web.1]: Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.1 Please log in with your web browser and then try again. Learn more at
2012-11-16T17:21:28+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
```

after looking around my code, I tried making another user but this time it worked. Does anyone know why? I read in another post that this could be because it'll fail if too many users register at once (since too many emails are sent), but I don't think anyone was registering at that point since not many people know about my app.

smtp settings:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'pacific-ravine-3563.herokuapp.com',
  :user_name            => ENV["EMAIL"],
  :password             => ENV["PASSWORD"],
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'pacific-ravine-3563.herokuapp.com' }
```

Comment: Can you share (part of) your SMTP settings? If you’re using Gmail, maybe you need to disable two-factor authentication.

Comment: @BuckDoyle hey buck. I updated the question with the SMTP settings. I am using Gmail. Where would I disable two-factor authentication (and what is that?)

Answer (score 11):

Google might be blocking you until you prove you’re human. Try logging in to this Gmail account through a web browser. If it doesn’t work then, try visiting [this link](https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) while logged in and completing the test.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone, I had to go here and "recognize" the activity as my own (it was coming from a server hosted by Heroku): https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity